# Whether someone able to see the profile users visited history?

Tags: support

Profile view depends on the number of users visited the profile.Is it possible to see the list who is visited my profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that information is not available.

Whether Stack Exchange record it or not I'm not sure, but it's definitely not exposed to users.

Comment: On MSE one of the devs once mentioned that they only prevent short time revisits to be counted as separate views... Can't find reference now, but it would suggest that even if they store this information, it does not live long.